# Django model nested serializer

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-serializer

I have the model structure like below

```
class BaseProduct:
   id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product
   base_product = ForeigKey(BaseProduct)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Condition:
   category = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='allowed_product')
   check = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   allow = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

The query:

```
Product.objects.filter(condition__allow=1, condition__check=1)
```

I want format something like below
**Base Product and inside that list of products** based on allow and check filter

```
[
    {
        "name": "BaseProduct 1",
        "products": [
            {

                "name": "TV",

            }, {}, ....

        ]
    },
........
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it, if you use django rest framework

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.fields import empty
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name')


class BaseProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = BaseProduct
        fields = ('name', 'products')

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
        self._condition_allow = kwargs.pop('condition_allow', 1)
        super(BaseProductSerializer, self).__init__(instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs)

    @cached_property
    def _request_data(self):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        # if POST
        # return request.data if request else {}
        # if GET params
        return request.query_params if request else {}

    @cached_property
    def _condition(self):
         return self._request_data.get('CONDITION_PARAM_NAME')

    def get_products(self, obj):
        qs = obj.product_set.filter(condition__allow=self._condition_allow, condition__check=1)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(qs, many=True)
        #                             ^^^^^
        return serializer.data
```

in view

```
serialiser(qs, condition_allow=5)
```

Comment: How can I pass the condition check inside serializer ? condition__check =1 from the view  (value 1 this can vary.)?

Comment: @RoshanA edit with example parameters from request, all information for DRF

Comment: Hi Thanks. the condition param is not from request. I have to process inside view based on query param and find the id. How can directly pass that id into serializer to get the data.

Comment: @RoshanA glad to help, i edit with added __init__ method, and new import, also changed get_products

Comment: attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead error ?

Comment: try replace `serializer = ProductSerializer(instance=qs, many=True)` to `serializer = ProductSerializer(qs, many=True)`. i edit answer

Comment: if we have 100 base product and 10 product each. then query will run 100 times with baseproduct id 1,2,3,..100.. Can we do this in one query using adjacency list single model. on one table ?

Comment: you can send to the initial data of the serializer list(qs) instead the condition_allow of the products.

Answer (score 1):

Change your models to have `related_name` for the foreignkeys to have reverse relationship:

```
class BaseProduct:
   id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product
   base_product = ForeigKey(BaseProduct, related_name='products')
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Condition:
   category = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='conditions')
   check = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   allow = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

So now you can use it in your serializers:

```
class BaseProductSerializer:
   class Meta:
    model = BaseProduct
    fields = ('name', 'products',)

class ProductSerializer:
   class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('conditions',)

class ConditionSerializer:
   class Meta:
    model = Condition
    fields = '__all__'
```

Finally in your views, change this:

```
Product.objects.filter(condition__allow=1, condition__check=1)
```

into this:

```
BaseProduct.objects.filter(products__conditions__allow=1, products__conditions__allow=1)
```

And hopefully, this should generate JSON data in the format that you asked for.

Comment: The way inner joins works is wrong. this query wont give correct result.